# setState in onViewportChanged results in crash when clicking marker with off-map popup (auto

Tags: javascript, react-leaflet

Click the marker when it it on the top edge of the map:
https://codepen.io/timkelty/pen/NWqdaVR

It seems to result in an endless loop of viewport updates, which crashes the map.

Note: if I set `autoPan={false}` on the popup, this doesn't happen, but then it doesn't pan to the open popup like I want.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is caused by a combination of the following factors:

- auto-panning when an open popup is out of the viewport causes React
  to re-render map component (see the below example how to avoid it)
- updating Map `viewport` property explicitly causes React again to re-render a map which is redundant operation since viewport is getting updated once auto-panning is triggered

One solution to consider would be to instruct a React to ***skip** re-rendering of map component* when auto-panning the map on open popup is triggered. The following component illustrates how to prevent map component from re-render:

```
const MapComponent = React.memo(props => {
  
   const {defaultViewport,...mapProps} = props;   
   
   return (
         <LeafletMap
          viewport={defaultViewport}
          {...mapProps}
        >
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url='https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
          />
          <Marker position={ [45.75219336063106, -84.49035644531251]} >
            <Popup>
              <div style={{minHeight: '300px'}}>My Popup</div>
            </Popup>
          </Marker>
        </LeafletMap>
     )
  
}, areEqual);
```

Now the example which demonstrates how to track current viewport could look like this:

```
const Example = () => {
  
  const [currentViewport, setCurrentViewport] = React.useState(defaultViewPort);
  const [viewportChanges, setViewportChanges] = React.useState(0);
  
  
  onViewportChanged = (viewport) => {
    setCurrentViewport(viewport);
    setViewportChanges(prevViewportChanges => prevViewportChanges + 1);
  }
  

  return (
      <div>
        <MapComponent
          bounds={michiganBounds}
          defaultViewport={defaultViewPort}
          onViewportChanged={onViewportChanged}>
        </MapComponent>
        Viewport changes: {viewportChanges}
        Current viewport: {JSON.stringify(currentViewport)}
      </div>
    );
}
```

Here is an [updated Codepen](https://codepen.io/vgrem/pen/KKVbyJe)